# jquery html() functions puts text on a new line

Tags: jquery, html, dom

When I use the `.html()` function, the text is added to a newline instead of inline.

Even when I stick it in a new table cell, it always appears below row I want it.

```
function add(id)
{
    $('#d'+id).html("Loading <img src='Images/loadingGIF.gif'>");
}
```

HTML:

```
<p><input type="submit" onclick="add(25)"> <div id="d25"></div>
<p><input type="submit" onclick="add(26)"> <div id="d26"></div>
```

How do I get the loading message to show up on the same line as the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DIVs do not generally stay inline. Try replacing the div with a span. If that does not work, style the DIV like so:

```
display: inline;
```

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? "Try replacing the div with a span" I only suggested the inline thing if for some weird reason the span doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

That's a property of `<div>` ... you can use `<span>` for the quickest fix